# Antenna selection for CC1101-433 MHz rf

Tags: antenna, radio, pcb-antenna, 433mhz

I intend to use these [TI CC1101 433 MHz RF modules](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/antenna-433-mhz-rf-module-CC1101_60472799827.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.131.4d9a531dRANYoY) in one of my project:

[image]

Wavelength of 433 MHz will be 69 cm. Half wavelength will be 34.5 cm. Vendor is selling two antenna options with the product. Both are spring coil type. One has length of 25 cm and the other has a length of 30 cm when the coil is straightened out. In one other product, I have seen an antenna which is a straight wire and of length 24 cm.

Q-1) Since all of these antenna are deviating from half wavelength, what's the reason behind making these antenna shorter than half wavelength? What length should give me the best range theoretically?

Q-2) If I want an omni-directional behavior, is it going to matter if I keep the antenna coiled or straight wire? If yes, which type will give better omni-directional performance?

Antenna like this are also available and being used in official launchpads of texas instruments:

[image]

Example:

[image: launchpad]

Q-3) How do these compare to coil, wire antenna?

Comment: Don't forget that that coil antenna has an inductance to it.

Comment: @Hearth - is that a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: Both.  An *appropriately* inductively loaded antenna can be physically smaller which may suit a particular product, but it will not perform as well as a full sized one. 
 This is not a question which can be simply or specifically answered, without modeling or measuring a given actual antenna.  You may find it simpler for a personal project to start by seeing if what is readily available meets your needs.